# jekyll serve (locally) without building

Tags: html, node.js, jekyll

Jekyll generates a static site in a given directory (by default, `_site`).  Running `jekyll serve` builds the site and then sets up a server such that the site can be viewed locally on the specified port (e.g. `localhost:4000` by default). I'm wondering if there is a way to activate this `serve` behavior without triggering the gem to recompile the site first.

Alternatively, it would be sufficient to use some other tool to serve the site from a localhost port without using jekyll, but I'm not sure how to do that (node.js?).  While I can open the static files directly in a browser, this doesn't find all the relative url links (to css, etc) correctly, defaulting links such as `/css/default.css` to the root `file://css/default.css` instead, which of course does not exist there.

(This would be useful, for instance, because Jekyll takes quite some time to build a large site, and certain plugins I use need internet access to various APIs.  It would be nice to view the site offline without triggering these).

Comment: If you just need a static file server, you can use [`node-static`](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static#command-line-interface). But, if the site's still building, the files may not actually be available yet.

Comment: Hmm.. Installs fine with `npm`, but when I try `static` in the site directory I get no console output and nothing visible at localhost:8080... not sure what I missed...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
jekyll serve --skip-initial-build
```

This will serve the site, skipping the initial build process. Additional configuration options for building and serving the site can be found [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to serve an already built `_site` directory, there are any number of ways to quickly run a web server locally. With ruby you can just `cd` into `_site` and use WEBrick like so:

```
ruby -rwebrick -e 'WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>4000,:DocumentRoot=>".").start'
```

or python's SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python -mSimpleHTTPServer 4000
```

Both these set the port to 4000, but that could be any number.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Both worked like a charm for me. The WEBrick appears to be what jekyll is using internally too.

Comment: Running ruby 2.5.1 and WEBrick 1.4.2 on windows I found this didn't work as written.  However after swapping the single and double quotes around it is working a charm i.e. `ruby -rwebrick -e "WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>4000,:DocumentRoot=>'.').start"`